# What happens when someone +1 a post by Google+ pages/users?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

I heard it is supposed to create a story, like on Facebook. but I've never seen any content on my Google+ wall other than the posts by persons in my circles.

On Facebook wall we also see images or links liked by our friends, even if we are not following those pages or peoples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**+1 activity updates in the stream, also for Pages**

When you +1 a post, people in your extended circles who also have you in circles may see this +1 "activity update" in their streams.  They will only see the activity update if they had access to the original post. Activity updates may also be visible in Google+ search results to anyone who can see the original post.

You can control how often you see activity updates from certain circles as well as control who sees your activity updates in their stream.

Read how to control your settings:
https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3113301?hl=en

See the screenshots in this [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/109164280656499025716/posts/3U5P5VdD7WD)

- Click on the Settings at the bottom of the left bar
- Click on Manage Apps & activities
- Change the visibility of *your +1's* from Only you - Circles - Extended circles - Public

Comment: A good resource for more information:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1k7AL2UY0EA1tQ5JjqEDbW5GWCp26ZPo0lDKQdAyfILw/edit?forcehl=1&hl=en#slide=id.g117444570_0156

Answer (score 2):

By default, I think they show up as part of your profile on Google+.  You should see a +1 tab with content that you have +1'd (is that a verb?)

There's documentation / marketing material about it [here](http://www.google.com/+1/button/).  I believe you can toggle some [setting](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047279?rd=1) to have your +1s show up to people in your circles.

Comment: Sorry, I should made my question more clear. I mean +1s on Google+ page's posts. apparently only +1s in other websites will show in the "+1 tab" in the profile.

Comment: I'm not sure.  At the very least I'm sure they feed back into Google's algorithms to deliver targeted ads or content.

Comment: About +1s on websites, according to the documentation that you provided, it seems +1s are more about Google search results, and if a user wants to share the content too, they should share the post using the dialog that will open after +1'ing a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

When you +1 a post, people in your extended circles may see it in their stream.

I just found this on Google:

> **[+1 activity updates in the stream](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3113301?p=plusone_posts&rd=1)**
>
> When you +1 a post, people in your extended circles who also have you
>   in circles may see this +1 "activity update" in their streams.  They
>   will only see the activity update if they had access to the original
>   post. Activity updates may also be visible in Google+ search results
>   to anyone who can see the original post.